# Show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{(f(x+2)+f(x)-2f(x+1))}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ twice differentiable and $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{f''(x)}=0$. Show that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{(f(x+2)+f(x)-2f(x+1))}=0$$

I have done the following:

Mean value theorem for $f$ on $[x,x+1]$: $$f'(a)=f(x+1)-f(x), x \leq a \leq x+1$$
Mean value theorem for $f$ on $[x+1, x+2]$: $$f'(b)=f(x+2)-f(x+1), x+1 \leq b \leq x+2$$
Mean value theorem for $f'$ on $[x,x+1]$: $$f''(c)=f'(x+1)-f'(x), x \leq c \leq x+1$$
Mean value theorem for $f'$ on $[x+1, x+2]$: $$f''(d)=f'(x+2)-f'(x+1), x+1 \leq d \leq x+2$$

$$$$

- If $f'$ is increasing:

  $f''(c)=f'(x+1)-f'(x) \leq f(x+2)-f(x+1)-f(x+1)+f(x)=f(x+2)+f(x)-2
     f(x+1)$

  Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{f''(x)}=0$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow
     +\infty}{f''(c)}=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{f(x+2)+f(x)-2 f(x+1)}=0 $
- If $f'$ is decreasing:

  $f''(d)=f'(x+2)-f'(x) \leq f(x+2)-f(x+1)-f(x+1)+f(x)=f(x+2)+f(x)-2
     f(x+1)$

  Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{f''(x)}=0$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 
     +\infty}{f''(d)}=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{f(x+2)+f(x)-2 f(x+1)}=0 $

$$$$
Is the way I solved it correct???

Comment: I wonder if $f(x+2)+f(x)-2f(x+1)=[f(x+2)-f(x+1)]-[f(x+1)-f(x)]$ could be useful.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici This would be equal to $$f'(b)-f'(a)$$ Do we have to use the mean value theorem at $[a,b]$ for $f'$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A=$f(x+2)+f(x)-2f(x+1)=f(x+2)-f(x+1)+f(x)-f(x+1)=f'(c)-f'(d)$ for some $c,d$ obtained by the mean value theorem.

So by applying the same theorem once again, $A=(c-d).f''(t)$ for some $t$. As x tends to infinity, t does too. Therefore $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}{f(x+2)+f(x)-2 f(x+1)}=0 $.

Comment: Great!!! Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: You are welcome.